# Rails Google maps javascript api v3 setIcon() url can't locate image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm changing the marker image upon mouseover of an element on the page, using the setIcon() method. It works fine when the url is something like this:

```
marker.setIcon('https://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker_green.png');
```

but when I try to get it to find an image in my local application directory, it can't find the image (the original marker image disappears but the new one doesn't appear):

```
marker.setIcon('images/myMarker.png');
```

I've tried every possible url (app/assets/images/myMarker.png, /images/myMarker.png, assets/images/myMarker.png, etc), and also placed the image in many different locations, it still doesn't work.

How do I get the javascript to find my png??

Comment: have you tried an absolute url instead of a relative url?

Comment: What would that look like? I've tried stuff like `http://localhost:3000/app/assets/images/myMarker.png` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it is an asset pipeline error i.e `marker_green.png` becomes something like `marker_green-336339d13ed7edf253018e0f7f70bee2.png` in production. Here are a couple of solutions:

1. Place the marker_green.png file in a public directory e.g. public/mapfiles/marker_green.png

or

2. Set a data attribute for the image path on a html element such as the div which loads the map and get is using JS/jQuery. i.e:

HTML:

```
<div id="map" data-marker-url="<%= asset_url('marker_green.png') %>"></div>
```

JS:

```
var markerIcon = $("#map").data('marker-url');
marker.setIcon(markerIcon);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this is an issue with the rails asset pipeline.  Here are a few options you can try:

1) Forget about the asset pipeline (not ideal), and move your marker to public/images. marker.setIcon('images/myMarker.png'); should then work.

2) Add the .erb extension to your file, and use asset_url to get the proper asset path when referring to the image: marker.setIcon("<%= asset_url('marker_green.png') %>");

It would be good to read through the [asset pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to figure out what will work with your configuration.